# Compact a comma delimited number list into ranges

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, range, java-stream

I'm looking for a clever way to do the following operation:

Take a list of numbers:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 19

and compact it into a string like so:

1-5, 12-14, 19

With the following rule: only compress into a range (i.e. use a dash) when the count of numbers in the range is 3 or more.

I.e.: 1, 2, 4, 5 would result in: 1, 2, 4, 5 and NOT: 1-2, 4-5

Comment: *did you already try something?* have you put some effort into this?

Comment: Doesn't seem like something you'd want to do with streams

Comment: "Please do my homework for me"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can only think about a custom collector... You can obviously create a method that would return this collector and the code would be really compact in this case, provided that the collector is hidden via a static factory method.

Notice how the `combiner` is doing basically nothing, not good for parallel coding. I'm still trying to think of a good way to provide an implementation for it.

```
 List<String> result = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 19)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collector.of(
                    () -> {
                        List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        list.add(new ArrayList<>());
                        return list;
                    },
                    (list, x) -> {
                        List<Integer> inner = list.get(list.size() - 1);
                        if (inner.size() == 0) {
                            inner.add(x);
                        } else {
                            int lastElement = inner.get(inner.size() - 1);
                            if (lastElement == x - 1) {
                                inner.add(x);
                            } else {
                                List<Integer> oneMore = new ArrayList<>();
                                oneMore.add(x);
                                list.add(oneMore);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    (left, right) -> {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No parallel!");
                    },

                    list -> {

                        return list.stream()
                                .map(inner -> {
                                    if (inner.size() > 1) {
                                        return inner.get(0) + "-" + inner.get(inner.size() - 1);
                                    }
                                    return "" + inner.get(0);
                                }).collect(Collectors.toList());

                    }));

    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Maybe extract this implementation to a seperate class, for reusability? like I did ;)

Comment: Maybe you are disturbed by the algorithm yesterday. up and thanks for your test yesterday.

Comment: @holi-java Im running them again today... Will update that post once Im done

Comment: @Eugene really? I'll see your new post later.

Answer (score 10):

Now that we have seen several Stream variants, here the non-Stream variant for comparison:

```
private static StringBuilder appendRange(StringBuilder sb, int start, int previous) {
    sb.append(start);
    if(start!=previous) sb.append(previous-start>1? " - ": ", ").append(previous);
    return sb;
}
```

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 19);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
int previous = list.get(0), start = previous;
for(int next: list.subList(1, list.size())) {
    if(previous+1 != next) {
        appendRange(sb, start, previous).append(", ");
        start = next;
    }
    previous = next;
}
String result = appendRange(sb, start, previous).toString();
```

Comment: your answer working fine ! but, i need using java-8 stream() . thanks for share your opinion .

Comment: That’s not a natural requirement to “need using java-8 stream()”. You can pick any of the other, incomplete (e.g. not compatible with parallel streams), much more complicated stream based solutions. If this is an assignment, it might be useful to answer showing both variants to demonstrate that this task is not really suitable for using the Stream API.

Comment: @Holger I agree on. what the OP want is get the continuous number ranges. sadly, I misread his requirement. I'll update my answer later.

Answer (score 4):

### Edit

I'm sorry, I misunderstand your requirement since my English is so bad. Thank everybody of forgiveness. I'll give a configurable `compress` method later to thank everybody.

After working, I found I can't apply your rule above by use stream easily: "***the count of numbers in the range is 3 or more.***" . so I down to the traditional approach. I wish it can helped you.

```
//        v--- "1-5, 12-14, 19"
String ranges = compress(asList(1,2,3,4,5, 12,13,14, 19)).collect(joining(", "));

//              v--- ["1", "2"]
Stream<String> lessThan3 = compress(asList(1, 2));

//              v--- ["1-4"]
Stream<String> step2 = compress(asList(1, 3, 4), 2, 3);
```

---

Build the range of `Stream<String>` immediately by using `Stream.Builder`.

```
static Stream<String> compress(List<Integer> numbers) {
    return compress(numbers, 1, 3);
}

static Stream<String> compress(List<Integer> numbers, int step, int minSize) {
    Builder<String> ranges = Stream.builder();
    IntBuffer queue = IntBuffer.allocate(minSize + 1);
    for (int it : numbers) {
        int prev = queue.position() - 1;
        if (prev >= 0 && queue.get(prev) + step < it) {
            copy(queue, ranges, minSize);
            queue.put(it);
        } else {
            if (queue.hasRemaining()) {
                queue.put(it);
            } else {
                queue.put(prev, it);
            }
        }
    }
    return copy(queue, ranges, minSize).build();
}

static Builder<String> copy(IntBuffer queue, Builder<String> target, int minSize) {
    queue.flip();
    if (queue.limit() >= minSize) {
        target.add(format("%d-%d", queue.get(0), queue.get(queue.limit() - 1)));
    } else {
        while (queue.hasRemaining()) target.add(Integer.toString(queue.get()));
    }
    queue.clear();
    return target;
}
```

### Edit2

Build the range of `Stream<String>` lazily by using `Spliterator`.

```
static Stream<String> compress(List<Integer> numbers, int step, int minSize) {
    return compress(numbers, minSize, (prev, current) -> current - prev <= step);
}


static Stream<String> compress(List<Integer> numbers,
                               int minSize,
                               IntBiPredicate rule) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(numbers, minSize, rule), false);
}


static AbstractSpliterator<String> spliterator(List<Integer> numbers,
                                               int minSize,
                                               IntBiPredicate rule) {
    return new AbstractSpliterator<String>(numbers.size(), ORDERED) {
        private Iterator<Integer> data;
        private Queue<String> queue;
        private IntBuffer buff;


        @Override
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super String> action) {
            init();
            return tryConsuming(action) || evaluate();
        }

        private void init() {
            if (data != null) return;
            data = numbers.iterator();
            queue = new LinkedList<>();
            buff = IntBuffer.allocate(minSize + 1);
        }

        private boolean tryConsuming(Consumer<? super String> action) {
            if (queue.isEmpty()) return false;
            action.accept(queue.poll());
            return true;
        }

        private boolean evaluate() {
            if (!data.hasNext()) {
                return buff.position() > 0 && fill();
            } else {
                evaluateNext(data.next());
                return true;
            }
        }

        private void evaluateNext(int it) {
            int prev = buff.position() - 1;
            if (prev >= 0 && !rule.test(buff.get(prev), it)) {
                fill();
                buff.put(it);
            } else {
                if (!buff.hasRemaining()) {
                    buff.put(buff.position() - 1, it);
                } else {
                    buff.put(it);
                }
            }
        }

        private boolean fill() {
            buff.flip();
            if (buff.limit() >= minSize) {
                int min = buff.get(0);
                int max = buff.get(buff.limit() - 1);
                queue.add(format("%d-%d", min, max));
            } else {
                while (buff.hasRemaining()) {
                    queue.add(Integer.toString(buff.get()));
                }
            }
            buff.clear();
            return true;
        }
    };
}

interface IntBiPredicate {
    boolean test(int first, int second);
}
```

### Oldest

How about this? `String` ranges are grouped by `n/m`:

```
int m = 5 + 1; 
//        v--- "1-5, 12-14, 19"
String ranges =
     Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 19)
           //       v--- calculate ranges until grouping is done
           .collect(collectingAndThen(
                groupingBy(
                    //     v--- group n by n/m
                    n -> n / m,
                    TreeMap::new,
                    // v--- summarizing the current group
                    summarizingInt(Integer::intValue) 
                ),
                summary -> summary.values()
                                  .stream()
                                  .map(
                       //create range string from IntSummaryStats ---v        
                                      it ->String.format(
                                          it.getMin()==it.getMax()?"%d":"%d-%d",
                                          it.getMin(),
                                          it.getMax()
                                      )
                                  )
                                  .collect(joining(", "))
            ));
```

Comment: can you explain a bit what you're doing?

Comment: @Lino hey, can you understand it now?

Comment: @holi-java that's actually pretty darn smart... to divide and group on that! very nice; the only thing is that you need an addition like `Collectors.andThen` probably, to actually produce a `List` of `String`s, like the OP wants.

Comment: @Eugene yeah. I don't know what's type of range the OP want, so I use a `int[]` instead.

Comment: @holi-java `and compact it into a string like so` - he wants strings...

Comment: @Eugene thanks for your feedback, sir. I'll fix it later. :)

Comment: Doing `mapping(identity(), …)` has no effect; it’s entirely obsolete. Besides that, I can’t recognize, how that magic number for `m` works. It happens to produce the right answer for this particular input, but how do you get that? What would be the right `m` if my input is, e.g. `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13, 14, 17`? Is there an `m` appropriate for this input at all?

Comment: @Holger sir, thanks for audit my answer, I'll fix the answer now. the `m` is not appropriate for your thoughts. my thoughts is group by `n/m`. it's different with yours.

Comment: your answer working fine! , but i want make this dynamically .. i didn't know how many range occurred in the array set. you mentions int m =5+1 that means, max 5 range "static" . thanks for advanced.

Comment: A solution that only works with one particular example input, isn’t a solution. Otherwise, I could just claim `String result = "1-5, 12-14, 19";` was a solution to this particular problem.

Comment: @amran_bd Not at all. glad it helped you. but you must note it is not `max 5 range "static"`, it is grouped by `n/m`.

Comment: @Holger because the OP don't describe it exactly. I has misread him. thanks for your feedback again.

Comment: @holi-java If you change your m value .. like 2 or 3 you can see what happen?

Comment: @amran_bd I'm sorry, sir. I misread your requirement ago.  to thanks your forgiveness, I give a configurable one `compress` method to you, I wish it can helped you.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a specific implementation of `Collector` which should do what you want.

> NOTICE: this implementation **fails horribly** when trying to use in parallel

```
public class RangeCollector implements Collector<Integer, List<String>, List<String>>{

    private int last = 0;
    private LinkedList<Integer> intermediate = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    public Supplier<List<String>> supplier(){
        return ArrayList::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<List<String>, Integer> accumulator(){
        return ( finalList, current ) -> {
            if( current - last == 1 ){ // check if adjacent to last value
                intermediate.add(current);
            } else{
                if( intermediate.size() > 2 ){
                    finalList.add(intermediate.getFirst() + "-" + intermediate.getLast()); // add new range
                } else{
                    addLeftOverValues(finalList);
                }
                intermediate.clear();
                intermediate.add(current);
            }
            last = current;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<List<String>> combiner(){
        return (list, list2) -> {
            list.addAll(list2);
            return list;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<List<String>, List<String>> finisher(){
        return ( finalList ) -> {
            if( !intermediate.isEmpty() ){
                addLeftOverValues(finalList);
            }
            return finalList;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics(){
        return EnumSet.noneOf(Characteristics.class);
    }

    private void addLeftOverValues( List<String> list ){
        list.addAll(
            intermediate.stream()
                .map(String::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
       );
    }
}
```

which then can be used like this:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12, 13, 14, 19);
System.out.println(list.stream().collect(new RangeCollector()));
```

which finally prints `[1-6, 12-14, 19]`

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest solution that is even more compact:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

public class CompactComaDelimitedNumbersTest {

    @Test
    public void testCompactingNumbersWithJavaStream() {
        //given:
        final List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 19);

        //when:
        final List<Object> finalResult = list.stream()
                // Firstly let's pair every number with a number it starts from in
                // given sequence
                .reduce(new ArrayList<Pair<Integer, Integer>>(), (result, number) -> {
                    if (result.isEmpty()) {
                        result.add(new Pair<>(number, number));
                        return result;
                    }

                    final Pair<Integer, Integer> previous = result.get(result.size() - 1);
                    if (previous.getFirst() + 1 == number) {
                        result.add(new Pair<>(number, previous.getSecond()));
                    } else {
                        result.add(new Pair<>(number, number));
                    }
                    return result;
                }, (a, b) -> a)
                // Now let's group list of pair into a Map where key is a number 'from' and value is a list of values
                // in given sequence starting from 'from' number
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Pair::getSecond, Collectors.mapping(Pair::getFirst, Collectors.toList())))
                // Finally let's sort entry set and convert into expected format
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey))
                .map(e -> e.getValue().size() < 3 ?
                        e.getValue() :
                        Collections.singletonList(String.format("%d-%d", e.getValue().get(0), e.getValue().get(e.getValue().size() - 1))))
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        //then:
        assertThat(finalResult, is(equalTo(Arrays.asList("1-5", "12-14", 19))));

    }

    static final class Pair<T,K> {
        private final T first;
        private final K second;
        Pair(T first, K second) {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
        }
        public T getFirst() {
            return first;
        }

        public K getSecond() {
            return second;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Pair{" +
                    "first=" + first +
                    ", second=" + second +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

It pairs every number with a starting number for a current sequence, then groups all pairs by this `from` number and lastly it converts map into list of ranges like `1-5` or plain numbers. I hope you like this solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is array range compacting. Here is a Python solution:

```
" """"considering input as "1,2,3,4,5,6,11,13,11,23" """" "


arr=list(map(int,input().strip().split(',')))
arr=list(set(arr))
arr.sort()
l2=[arr[0]]
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if i+1<len(arr) and i-1>-1:
        if arr[i]-arr[i-1]==1 and  arr[i+1]-arr[i]==1 :
            if  l2[-1]!='-':
                l2+=['-']
            else:
                l2=l2
        else:
                l2+=[arr[i]]
if len(arr)>1:
    l2+=[arr[len(arr)-1]]       
st=str(l2[0])
for i in range(1,len(l2)):
    if str(type(l2[i]))!=str(type(l2[i-1])):
        st+=str(l2[i])
    else:
        st+=','+str(l2[i])
print(st,sep='\n')
```

I know this is very bad code and not so optimum one yet. If someone needs help he can refer to this one. Edits are welcome, to make the code in Python using good data structure.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to make it as simple as possible, you need to first initialise a start value, a start position variable and an end position variable. Keep on incrementing the start variable if it is consecutive, or else make start and end position as the current position variable and append the result. In case the difference in position of start and end is zero, just append one value of that position. In case the value is one, add both the values individually. In case it is greater than one, add the start and end position variables to the result separated by a dash.

```
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 19]
nums.sort()
print(nums)
res = []


# Initialise the values for start and end position variables along with the start
start = nums[0]
sPos = 0
ePos = 0

for i in range(1,len(nums)):
    if nums[i] == start+1:
        # Keep incrementing ePos and start if the numbers are consecutive
        ePos = i
        start=start+1
    else:
        # In case there is a break in the sequence, calculate the difference between start and end
        if sPos == ePos:
            # If both pointing at same place add the element
            res.append(nums[sPos])
        elif ePos - sPos == 1:
            # In case there are just 2 numbers then add both of them
            res.append(nums[sPos])
            res.append(nums[ePos])
        else:
            # In case there are more than 2 numbers, then add the start and end with dash in between
            res.append(str(nums[sPos])+"-"+str(nums[ePos]))
        start = nums[i]
        sPos = i
        ePos = i
# Finally just check in the same manner for the last elements
if sPos == ePos:
    res.append(nums[sPos])
elif ePos - sPos == 1:
    res.append(nums[sPos])
    res.append(nums[ePos])
else:
    res.append(str(nums[sPos])+"-"+str(nums[ePos]))
start = nums[i]
sPos = i
ePos = i
print(res)
```